# How do I add onClick() on a Select Dropdown via React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-i18next, language-translation

I'm trying to apply reactI18next on a project, normally you to toggle the language change you would create a button that would call the "changelanguage" function like this:

```
  const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  }

<button onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>en</button>
```

However, I was wondering if it's possible to make something similar but In a dropdown fashion.

Is there a way to trigger an onClick via select or other means?

Thanks and I hope to hear you guys soon!

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, you can add `onChange` event handler on Select tag such as

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [lang , setLang] = useState('en')

  function changeLanguage(event){
    // i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value)
    setLang(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>{lang}</p>
      <select value={lang} onChange={changeLanguage}>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can test on working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-cloud-3ejcw3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: hello, i would need to declare the 2 languages, how would you go about that

Comment: you can change values of languages in option tag

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `onChange` prop on the `<select>` element.

```
import { useState } from "react";
const languages = {
  en: "English",
  ta: "Tagalog",
  es: "Español"
};

export default function App() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("en");
  function onChange(e) {
    il18n.changeLanguage(e.target.value); // Use your library here
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label for="lang">Choose a language: </label>
      <select name="lang" id="lang" onChange={onChange}>
        {Object.keys(languages).map((languageKey) => (
          <option key={languageKey} value={languageKey}>
            {languages[languageKey]}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <br />
      <br />
      <p>Currently selected:</p>
      <p>Key: {selectedValue}</p>
      <p>Value: {languages[selectedValue]}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit rough-field-7nygrx]

Comment: Is it possible to use this on a sperate component that would be imported?

Comment: Yeah. The cool thing with React is that you can modularize components as much as you like.

Comment: Ah well i was wondering how you would go about it as it seems that i'm having trouble getting it done, it's asking to declare the language tags e.g "en"

Comment: I mean isn't it as simple as doing this inside the `onChange` function:
`i18n.changeLanguage(e.target.value);`

Comment: You already have the language tags like `"en"` and `"es"` inside the `const languages`. So you can just use those language tags in the `il18n` package. I'm also assuming that you're the one who declares these language tags, correct?

Comment: yeah pretty much

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
const changeLanguage = (event) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value);
}
<select value={value} onChange={changeLanguage}>
    <option value="en">English</option>
</select>
```